# Java: How do I put array into JScrollPane();?

Tags: java

Here i am using databse connection and trying to retrieve all table names from database. Later as you can see those table names i get (using while loop) are stored in String [] tables, and then i add this string to my

```
List<String []> sqltable = new ArrayList<>();
```

In order to print them i am using for loop:

```
for (String [] tablename : sqltable)
```

So my question would be how i can use this for loop (or maybe not for loop if someone knows better method) to put this sqltable list into my listScrollPane?

```
JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
```

I already tried(but this not working because i cannot reach varibales form my while loop):

```
JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(Arrays.asList(sqltable));
```

Also tried creating method and store for loop in it, but by doing this i achieved null only.

My code snipet:

```
if (conn != null) {
     DatabaseMetaData metadata = conn.getMetaData();
     List<String []> sqltable = new ArrayList<>();
     try {                             
         String[] types = {"TABLE"};
         String[] tables;                             
         ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
         while (resultSet.next()) {
             tableName = resultSet.getString(3);
             tables = new String[]{tableName};
             sqltable.add(tables);                                 
         }
     } catch (SQLException ex) {  
         Logger.getLogger(JFDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     for (String [] tablename : sqltable){
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tablename));
         System.out.println(Arrays.asList(tablename));                         
     }
}
```

Comment: JScrollPane just gives you a Pane that can be scrolled. You need to add some content in to it, to put your list in.
For example a table, or ListBox etc....
BTW Why are you using String arrays inside an ArrayList ??

Comment: Ok i can use ArrayList<> a = new ArrayList<>, but this is not the problem, in both cases this is working, and for JScrollPane yes i know that i need to put some data, but i am asking not for that i am asking for proper way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not really sure I understand your code... You have a list of arrays... is it what you want?

Anyway I suggest you have a look at this short example, is wraps a JList in a JScrollPane.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestJScrollPaneWithList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String[]> sqlTable = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        sqlTable.add(new String[] { "test1" });
        sqlTable.add(new String[] { "test2" });
        sqlTable.add(new String[] { "test3" });

        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Test)");

        JList list = new JList(sqlTable.toArray());
        list.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                String[] val = (String[]) value;
                return new JLabel(val[0]);
            }
        });
        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        fr.add(listScrollPane);

        fr.setSize(100, 100);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I added a basic ListCellRenderer that displays the first element of each array in a a JLabel instead of the default array's toString.

Comment: I see your point your example is clear and everything is ok. But in other way you are doing all this in your main class so it's kinda easy to get list, but in my example, every variable is in if and while loops so i cant reach them like you do in your example

Comment: Yes, I wanted to provide a very short and basic example :-). I thought you could use it because I read "I already tried:JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(Arrays.asList(sqltable));" so I thought you could try JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JList(sqlTable.toArray())); the same way.

Comment: In one way i should thank you, u made list work great :) . But there comes other problem, because it printing me not strings but array object name: Ljava.lang.String;@264d8046, maybe you know the way of converting it to string somehow :)

Comment: Just added a basic ListCellRenderer example in my edit.

Comment: ty :) u are the best :)

Comment: Too kind! :-) consider this is a very basic example, you proably want to improve it to support focus, selection etc... I'm glad I could help anyway :-)

Comment: Ye, now started to read documentation of dropLocation, and how to make selecatble list :)

Comment: Wait, here you create custom ListCellRenderer ye? But it's not better to use implementation of class and use native ?

Comment: Yes, it can be... you have different options, you have to choose your best fit.